# my listview showing the first 5 item its repating the items in android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-viewholder

Hi Every one I'm facing with a problem in android what i need is I'm having a list view in my Fragment which is dynamically set with the values from database,  my list view view updating the list dynamically in that i am having 8 items the list showing the first 5 items and repeating the from the first my code is like this.please help me in this thanks in advance.please help me in this i am not able to find what is the error.
I have created the list view using Baseadapter.Thanks in advance

```
class FashionAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context context;
        String redu[];
        JSONArray article;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        private List<Fashion> articlelist;
        FashionAdapter(JSONArray article, Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.article = article;
            //this.content=content;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return article.length();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            try {
                return article.getJSONObject(position);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              ViewHolder holder;
            Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/eenadu-webfont.ttf");

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                        R.layout.fashoinlist_item, null);
                Log.d("item postion",""+ position);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                JSONObject FasionObject;
                try {
                    FasionObject=article.getJSONObject(position);
                    holder.fTitle.setText(FasionObject.getString("articletitle"));
                    holder.fsadec.setText(FasionObject.getString("articleshortdec"));
                    holder.fTitle.setTypeface(font);
                    holder.fsadec.setTypeface(font);
                     String articlThumImage=FasionObject.getString("articlethumbimg");
                     Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(articlThumImage).into(holder.fImage);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); // return last set view of ith item
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

i was written the view hloder class like this, in this i intilized all the views .
        class ViewHolder {

```
        ImageView fImage;
        TextView fsadec,fTitle;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            fImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fashion_image);
            fsadec=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fashion_sdec);
            fTitle=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fashion_title);
        }
```

please help me in this i am not able to find what is the error.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/1939564

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move below code outside if block

```
 JSONObject FasionObject;
            try {
                FasionObject=article.getJSONObject(position);
                holder.fTitle.setText(FasionObject.getString("articletitle"));
                holder.fsadec.setText(FasionObject.getString("articleshortdec"));
                holder.fTitle.setTypeface(font);
                holder.fsadec.setTypeface(font);
                 String articlThumImage=FasionObject.getString("articlethumbimg");
                 Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(articlThumImage).into(holder.fImage);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and write after else statement

```
  else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     } // return last set view of ith item
            JSONObject FasionObject;
            try {
                FasionObject=article.getJSONObject(position);
                                      holder.fTitle.setText(FasionObject.getString("articletitle"));
                holder.fsadec.setText(FasionObject.getString("articleshortdec"));
                holder.fTitle.setTypeface(font);
                holder.fsadec.setTypeface(font);
                 String articlThumImage=FasionObject.getString("articlethumbimg");
                 Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(articlThumImage).into(holder.fImage);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much can you please explain why it is like that

Comment: Because adapter reuses the views

Comment: @JuturuYugandhar My I know why did you unaceepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the adapter class using
https://www.buzzingandroid.com/tools/android-layout-finder/
and check the number of items entering from your database is proper or not.